# Creating a webscraping loop in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to setup a webscraping loop in R but I am really struggling with creating a loop which works.

I currently have an excel file which contains the relevant URLs which I would like to scrape. I read this into R and try to use a webscrape to extract the product title for each URL which are currently in the column titled `DE`. A short example of the table is :

[image]

The code I have been using is:

```
library(readxl)
URL_creator <- read_excel("URL creator.xlsx")

library(rvest)
content_list <- vector()
for (i in 1:nrow(URL_creator)) {
  url <- URL_creator[i,]$DE
  html <- read_html(url)
  nodes <- html_nodes(html, "productTitle") %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    gsub("\n", "", .) %>% 
    trimws()
  {    content_list[i] <- nodes[1]
    }}
```

For some reason the content list returned is blank. I was hoping it would return the product title for each of the corresponding URL's in the column titled `DE` but I'm not sure where I have gone wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could use `dput(x)` to provide the list of url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes in your code and works fine. Check it out:

```
for (i in URL_creator$DE) {
  html <- read_html(i)
  nodes <- html_nodes(html, "title") %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    gsub("\n", "", .) %>% 
    trimws()
  {    content_list[i] <- nodes[1]
    }}
```

The output for `content_list[1]` is:

> https://amazon.de/dp/B0821PBSPJ  "Planet Waves D'Addario 10MB00
> Mandolinengurt, geflochten, 2,5 cm, Braun/cremefarben : Amazon.de:
> Musikinstrumente & DJ-Equipment"

**UPDATE**

To transform the result (`content_list`) into data frame you should change the line:

```
content_list[i] <- nodes[1]
```

as below:

```
content_list[i] <- as.data.frame(nodes[1])%>%
t()
```

It converts the `content_list` into a data frame and transforms columns into rows.

Comment: Hi Bart,
Thanks so much for the help! Is there a way I can then take the output of content_list[i] for all i and have it as a coloumn of data in a data frame?

Comment: Hi, you should add some modification to the code I presented the other day:  

content_list[i] <- as.data.frame(nodes[1])%>%
      t()

Comment: Hi @NeccessaryConference , do you mind to flag my answer as useful if it solved your problem? I'll be really grateful as I'm trying to gain some reputation points. Best!

Comment: Hi @Bart I apologise but I'm too new to the platform for it to register my flag on the answer. I tried it anyway to see if it would give you the points- sorry I can't be of more help

Comment: All good, points granted. Thank you!